# Как выровнять все содержимое сайта по одной линии

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

К примеру, у меня на сайте есть хедер и какая-то контентная часть. Как сделать так ,чтобы при изменении расширения экрана, и хэдэр и контент всегда оставались на одной линии, то есть не разъезжались. `

```
<header>
<div class="content-header">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center header-content">
<div class="col-md-auto">
</div>
<div class="col-md-auto">
</div>
<div class="col-md-auto">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</header>
<section class="main-section">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row justify-content-center">
<div class="col-md-auto">
</div>
<div class="col-md-auto">
<form class="main-section-form" method="POST" action="/form.php" >
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score -1):

Можно указать одни и те же значения колонок в хэдэре и контенте. Но тогда придется прописывать значения для каждого из размеров (xs/sm/md/lg).
У вас col-md-auto выравнивает в Хедере и контенте по-разному, так как содержимое может различаться. Можно сделать значения, например: col-3 col-6 col-3 в хэдэре и контенте. Тогда ровно встанут col-3 под col-3...Только из-за этого, в зависимости от контента придется прописывать разные значения (xs/sm/md/lg). Но одинаковые для хэдэра и контента.

Comment: А о каких значениях идёт речь?

Comment: У вас col-md-auto выравнивает в Хедере и контенте по-разному, так как содержимое может различаться. Можно сделать значения, например: col-3 col-6 col-3 в хэдэре и контенте. Тогда ровно встанут col-3 под col-3...Только из-за этого, в зависимости от контента придется прописывать разные значения (xs/sm/md/lg). Но одинаковые для хэдэра и контента.